# "Please note" vs. "please notice"

Tags: word-choice, verbs, american-english

When I'm writing a text and want to ask the reader to pay close attention to a point, should I write "Please note" or "Please notice"? Is there any difference?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. As it stands this question is incomplete. Please edit the question to explain the reason(s) and other context for the question and to share your prior research.

Answer (score 11):

It would normally be *Please note*. However, you may find that it isn't necessary at all.

Comment: Good point. It often isn't.

Comment: Please note that _please note that_ often isn't necessary at all.

Answer (score 7):

In your scenario, I think you should use "please note". "Please notice" seems to be more official.

Comment: I'm writing a scientific paper.

Answer (score 6):

"Please note" would be usual. You want readers to pay particular attention to the point (one sense of *note*) rather than merely be aware of it. *Note* also makes more sense as an active exhortation.

The abbreviation *NB* is often used too (for *nota bene*, "note well").